# Unable to autoload constant in API Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I'm trying to setup a RoR API but I'm hitting a few roadbump along the way. After tiresome coding to get the database setup right I'm hitting an error that doesn't quite make sense to me (I'm new to RoR)

`Unable to autoload constant Api::V1::SubmissionsController, expected ./app/controllers/api/v1/submissions_controller.rb to define it`

I'm not quite sure what this error means and my interwebs searches are coming up empty on a clear answer. I'm hoping any of you can help me here.

Routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
 namespace :api, :defaults => {:format => :json} do
   namespace :v1 do
     get "/submissions", to: "submissions#index"
   end
 end
end
```

submission.rb

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

submissions_controller.rb

```
class API::V1::SubmissionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
   @submissions = Submission.all
   render json: @submissions, status: :ok
  end
end
```

Comment: Does `app/controllers/api/v1/submissions_controller.rb` define that controller?

Comment: I mean is the controller in that file?

Comment: Oh yeah it is in that file yeah

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your file contains:

```
class API::V1::SubmissionsController < ApplicationController
```

Rails expects:

```
class Api::V1::SubmissionsController < ApplicationController
```

Comment: Thanks man. Is there a guide somewhere on naming conventions in ruby ?

Comment: @NicolasPierre Probably, but in general it's normal CamelCasing for class and module names.

Comment: Okay i'll look it up ;)

Answer (score 0):

What does your folder structure look like for app/controllers & app/views? Depending on how these files were generated, by "rails generate" or manually created, if you namespace, the folder structure has to match in controllers and views directories.

app/controllers/api/v1
app/views/api/v1

Comment: That's what I said in the comments.